# How to solve Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a chatroom application using react and firebase. Initially, I got an error while importing auth and firestore at once i.e import { auth, firestore } from 'react';, I tried firebase.auth(); and firebase.firestore(); and I got an error saying that 'auth not defined no-def' and 'firestore not defined no-def', now I have tried const auth = firestore.auth(); and const firestore = firebase.firestore() and I now get an error "Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)."...could someone please help me

Attached is my code

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
//import 'firebase/app';
//import { auth, firestore } from 'firebase';
//firebase.auth();
//firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore()

export const signup = (user) => {

    return async (dispatch) => {

        const db = firestore();
        auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user); 
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Carefully check, if your imports use firebase somehow. I have a vue3 project and I initialized firebase before creating the vue3 app as you certainly do with react. But in my case, I had an import which imported other classes and one of them used firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use any of the firebase SDKs you need to initialize your firebase App.

This code shows how you initialize the App:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";


// Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDOCAbC123dEf456GhI789jKl01-MnO",
  authDomain: "myapp-project-123.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://myapp-project-123.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "myapp-project-123",
  storageBucket: "myapp-project-123.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "65211879809",
  appId: "1:65211879909:web:3ae38ef1cdcb2e01fe5f0c",
  measurementId: "G-8GSGZQ44ST"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Don't forget to replace the configs with those of your firebase project.
[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object) you can see how to get your Firebase configuration.

After that you can run your code.

Make sure the initialization is called before any SDK is used. For that I would also recommend to change your code to this:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';
//import 'firebase/app';
//import { auth, firestore } from 'firebase';
//firebase.auth();
//firebase.firestore();


export const signup = (user) => {

    return async (dispatch) => {
       const auth = firebase.auth();
       const firestore = firebase.firestore()

        const db = firestore();
        auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user); 
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: I had already initialized my firebase app

Comment: Just the same exact way you enlisted yours

Comment: `//Web App's firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAuSFNSSRyiscvEG1QWxq0CMW9hJ9DqBec",
  authDomain: "learn-581c8.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "learn-581c8",
  storageBucket: "learn-581c8.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "443182491044",
  appId: "1:443182491044:web:fdfe00e957e98455794d31",
  measurementId: "G-T858M7FKTK"
};

//export auth = firebase.auth();
//export default firebase;

firebase.initializeApp(firebase.config)

window.store = store;`

Comment: @jamalkasule have you initialized it in the component where you are testing it? Assuming you are using react router or something

Comment: it sounds like a race condition between initialization and your app calling firebase methods.

Comment: It still didn't help

Comment: 'import firebase from 'firebase';
//import 'firebase/app';
//import { auth, firestore } from 'firebase';
//firebase.auth();
//firebase.firestore();

export const signup = (user) => {

    return async (dispatch) => {

        const db = firestore();
        auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user); 
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }
}

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

'

Comment: That's my code, the file where the error allegedly is

Comment: Can you pls share more code with us. The whole file where you initialize the app and the one where you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the firebase config file in index.js

```
import firebase.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Ensure this code is above any other thing you are importing if they are all in the same file e.g provider,auth, getAuth  e.tc. just any other method you are calling...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32746767)

Answer (score 0):

Happended to me for no reason too

Fixed the issue by import the config files with your credentials in root app

```
import app from './firebase/config'
console.log('app :', app);
```